# when i right click on selected tab and open it on new tab ,it always open the default active tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
<li class='active'>
   <a data-toggle='tab' href='#table' class="tab_list" > 
           <div>
                <span style="font-size: 16px;">Tweets</span>
           </div>

    </a> 
</li>
          

<li>
  <a data-toggle='tab' href='#summary' class="tab_list">
          <div>
            <span style="font-size: 16px;">Metrics</span>
         </div>
  </a> 
</li>


        


   


  <div class="tab-content " style=" background-color:;padding-left: ;">

<!--METRICS TAB-->
<div id='summary' class='tab-pane fade'>
<h1>abc</h1>
</div>
<!--METRICS TAB END-->


 <!--Tweets table TAB-->
<div id='table' class='tab-pane fade in active'>
<h1>abc</h1>
</div>
```

I Have multiple tab in my side navigation bar ,i want to open my selected tab in new browser tab, but when i right click on selected tab and open it on new tab ,it always open the default active tab.
I want to open the selected tab

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: What are you actually expecting? Please be clear what you actually looking for . Are you looking for someone to do all the codes for you?  Provide your code that you have already tried.

Comment: I provided my code

Comment: when i right click on my metric tab and open it on new browser tab it open the tweet table tab,which is default active tab,instead this default active tab  i want to open a metric tab

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript / jquery.  Check whether the url contains hash and if there is an id with the same name, show it by triggering click event.

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {   
            var url = $(location).attr('href');
            if(url.indexOf("#")) {
                var tabId = window.location.hash;
                console.log(tabId);
                console.log($('a[href="'+tabId+'"]').parent('li'));
                if($('a[href="'+tabId+'"]').parent('li').length){
                   $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').trigger('click');
                }
            }                
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: url does not contain hash#

Comment: What else i can do if it does not contain hash

Comment: Please paste the url here.  It must contain hash.